# java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no jmtp in java.library.path error while creating .jar file to .exe file using Launch4j software

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, unsatisfiedlinkerror

I am developing a GUI windows app in java.

I need to create an installer now. I got .jar file and now I am creating .exe file using Launch4j free s/w(I hope it is free s/w, Please let me know if it is paid one).

Project has many dependencies of external .jar files and .dll files.

I have included all jar files and dll files into Launch4j s/w when I run it getting the error as **"Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no jmtp in java.library.path"**

Please help me how to create a perfect executable file.

[image]

Comment: I'd try setting the java.library.path environment variable to point to your DLLs.  It's the CLASSPATH for native code; can't be loaded otherwise.

Comment: I also tried that by setting the .dll path in environment variable but getting the same error. After setting the class path do I need to restart system or close Install4j and open again.?

Comment: I don't use it; I don't know.  How did you set that environment variable - the tab up above?

Comment: Appended this E:\(complete path)\jmtp.dll; to path.

Comment: @user2085965 Are you using Netbeans to create jar file?

Comment: No, I am using Eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

Have edited my answer. Below is the working solution.

Add jar to yout project workspace. Here are the steps I followed in eclipse, to add DDL to project.

1.Create a folder under the project, for example dll. 2.Copy/paste all dll files into this folder. 3.In project -> Properties -> Java Build Path -> Source, click and expand the source details. 4.You will see Native library location, click on it. 5.Then click edit on the right, click workspace again. You can see the dll folder under the project. 6.Find it and click Ok. You will see the dll is added in the Native library location.

Post this do the following in run configuration. Say the dll you need is in Y:\path\to\dlls\lib. Then set your Run Configuration's working directory to Y:\path\to\dlls\ and set your VM arguments to include -Djava.library.path=lib

reference: Add .dll to java.library.path in Eclipse/PyDev Jython project

Comment: Sanjeevan, please don't add *Me too* as answers. It doesn't actually provide an answer to the question. If you have a different but related question, then [ask](/questions/ask) it (reference this one if it will help provide context). If you are interested in this specific question, you can [upvote](/help/privileges/vote-up) it, leave a [comment](/help/privileges/comment), or start a [bounty](/help/privileges/set-bounties) once you have enough [reputation](/help/whats-reputation).

Comment: ops.. I am extremly sorry about that @Yunnosch.. I was unaware.. My intension was to ask in comment.
Now,  I got it.. so wont do this mistake again. Thanks for explaining.